# How do you exclude items from AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to exclude items in an ng-repeat?

For example, I have something similar to the following (simplified to keep things shorter):

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="entry in data.feed.entry | orderBy:'gsx$timestamp.$t':true">
{{entry.gsx$jobID.$t}}
</div>
```

I have another scope object called *exclusionData* that is structured in a similar fashion.   I want to exclude any items in my first ng-repeat that appear in an *exclusionData.feed.entry.gsx$jobID.$t*

Or is there an easier way to do this back in my controller (i.e. do the exclusion in data right away)?  Both the data and the exclusionData is sourced from two different JSON feeds.

Comment: You should use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a filter shown below, or just an ng-if/ng-show

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="entry in data.feed.entry | orderBy:'gsx$timestamp.$t':true | filter: {gsx$exlucde.$t: true}">
{{entry.gsx$jobID.$t}}
</div>

data.feed.entry = [{
    gsx$jobID.$t: 'something',
    gsx$exlucde.$t: true,
    gsx$timestamp.$t: '1/1/1990'
}]
```

Comment: I was thinking of this, but the exclusionData is a different object.  For example entry in data.feed.entry vs entry in exclusionData.feed.entry

Comment: You could write a function to loop through the exclusion data and add it into the data.feed.entry data or you can just use a ng-if to check if the data is excluded

Comment: no, my code isn't dependent on it being sequential, it just happened to be placeholder data that came to mind.  The only thing that my code is reliant on is the fact that the excluded data is an array and use of the indexOf method to check if it exists.  If this is not the case for you then you could change the search functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This will exclude the matching data simply adding an ng-if, and adding a bang to make it falsy.

```
<div 
    class="row"
    data-ng-repeat="(key, entry) in data.feed.entry | orderBy:'gsx$timestamp.$t':true"
    ng-if="!exclusionData.feed[key]gsx$jobID.$t">
    {{entry.gsx$jobID.$t}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is with a filter directive in your repeat, but you could also do this in your controller.

It depends on how your application looks like from a OO design perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter like this:

```
angular.module('appFilters', []).filter('yourFilterName', function() {
    return function(input, key) {          
      var myList = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        var found = _.find($scope.exclusionData, function() { // You can replace this with your own function.
          // Your own logic here    
        });

        if(found){              
          myList.push(input[i]);
        }
      }
      return myList;
    };
  });
```

I am assuming you have underscore included in you project, but you can implement your own search function instead.

The in your template you pass the filter like this:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="entry in data.feed.entry | yourFilterName | orderBy:'gsx$timestamp.$t':true">
  {{entry.gsx$jobID.$t}}
</div>
```